# Why are documents in elasticsearch immutable?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get a hang of elasticsearch. Was reading through the [definitive guide](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html).

They've mentioned that the update API does a retrieve-change-reindex cycle 
each time I update something in a document. And I completely get that this is done because they say that "Documents are immutable"(see [this](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/update-doc.html)). What I am questioning here is why have it immutable in the first place. Wouldn't there be an advantage of allowing update and index of just a particular field hadn't this been the constraint?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First , it's better to tell segments are immutable than telling documents are immutable. To understand the reason. You need to understand how lucene works. Lucerne is a java library on top of which elasticsearch is built. Under the hood a single shard is a lucene instance and it does the actual work of documents storage and search . Elasticsearch is more of a distributed REST based server layer on top of lucene.

In lucene in order to achieve high Indexing speed we have segment architecture. A bunch of files are kept in a segment where each segment is a single file in the disk. As file in between write operation is very heavy , a segment is made immutable so that all subsequent writes go to New segments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Vineeth Mohan. One thing that I am still unclear is what will each file in segment contain. Going by your description, I get this picture: 

Bunch of files ---(constitutes)--> segments ---(represented by)-->file on disk

PS: I am yet to read the Lucene docs.

Comment: A single segment contains a set of documents  and all the meta data associated with it. To be precise meta data involves reverse index and other associated data structures. Similarly for a single shard ,there can be N number of segments , each handling its own set of documents.

Comment: So you're saying since documents can possibly span multiple segments and hence writing diff updates becomes so heavy that the cost is  approximately equal to writing a new document and hence the immutability?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is more related to Lucene, and as Vineeth Mohan said it's better to tell that segments are immutable. The reason that segments are immutable is about caching: Lucene relies a lot on the OS file system caching, to speed up reading. [Immutable segments are more cache friendly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#_give_less_than_half_your_memory_to_lucene):

> Lucene is designed to leverage the underlying OS for caching in-memory data structures. Lucene segments are stored in individual files. Because segments are immutable, these files never change. This makes them very cache friendly, and the underlying OS will happily keep hot segments resident in memory for faster access. These segments include both the inverted index (for fulltext search) and doc values (for aggregations).