# Delete / add nested objects in Elastic search

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

I cannot find examples in the [Elastic manual on nested objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) on how to modify fields and nested objects of documents using RESTful commands in Kibana Sense. I am looking for something similar to Solrs [atomic updates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents) here, which allow to update specific fields of documents.

How do RESTful commands in Kibana Sense look like that accomplish this? The only related info in the manual I can find is on [Partial Updates to Documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/partial-updates.html#_updates_and_conflicts), but I do not know how this can be applied for this use case.

For example, straight from the [Elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html):

```
PUT my_index
{
"mappings": {
    "my_type": {
    "properties": {
        "user": {
        "type": "nested" 
        }
    }
    }
}
}

PUT my_index/my_type/1
{
"group" : "fans",
"user" : [
    {
    "first" : "John",
    "last" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
    "first" : "Alice",
    "last" :  "White"
    }
]
}
```

How can I delete an entry in the nested object, so that the document "1" looks like:

```
{
"group" : "fans",
"user" : [
    {
    "first" : "John",
    "last" :  "Smith"
    }
]
}
```

How can I add an entry in the nested object, so that the document "1" looks like:

```
{
"group" : "fans",
"user" : [
    {
    "first" : "John",
    "last" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
    "first" : "Alice",
    "last" :  "White"
    },
    {
    "first" : "Peter",
    "last" :  "Parker"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use scripted updates unless you want to fetch all nested objects then add / remove items and re-index them all which is the previous answer proposed. However if you have a lot of nested documents you should be doing partial updates / additions and deletes. It is much quicker from data transfer and indexing point of view.

Here is a good article how to do scripted updates in general:

https://iridakos.com/programming/2019/05/02/add-update-delete-elasticsearch-nested-objects

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your ask, you just post the updated document version to the same document id each time you want.

To delete a nested document (or any field):

```
PUT my_index/my_type/1
{
  "group" : "fans",
  "user" : [
    {
      "first" : "Alice",
      "last" :  "White"
    }
  ]
}
```

To add a user, add it to the list:

```
PUT my_index/my_type/1
{
  "group" : "fans",
  "user" : [
    {
      "first" : "Alice",
      "last" :  "White"
    },
    {
      "first" : "Peter",
      "last" :  "Parker"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: [Documents in elasticsearch are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151566/why-are-documents-in-elasticsearch-immutable). Making a change to a single field causes the entire document to be re-indexed. Nested documents are always re-indexed with the parent document so if you change a field in the parent the nested document *is also* re-indexed. This can be a performance issue if the nested documents are large and the parents have frequent changes.

Comment: I want to add or delete within the nested "user" object, not re-index a new (potentially big) document again. I am looking for something similar to Solrs "atomic updates", I updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: What you want is not possible with elasticsearch. Documents are immutable. I adjusted my answer to include a note about this. You will probably want to un-nest the documents and link them through some application logic.

Comment: What about https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/partial-updates.html#_updates_and_conflicts (Partial Updates to Documents)? Could this be used to accomplish a RESTful command to directly update as in my example?

Comment: You can certainly use an update script but I'm not sure that is much better. Either way the entire document is still re-indexed after the update: see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html & https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html Let me know if it works the way you want.

Comment: Full re-indexing of the doc (behind the scenes, handled by Elastic) is OK, such an update operation should not happen often anyway. How would an update script look like for this?

Comment: This documentation should get you started: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-groovy.html. You'll want to manipulate the _source.user field.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific use case, you must use a scripted update. In javascript the call will look something like:

```js
    const documentUpdateInstructions = {
      index: "index-name",
      id: "document-id",
      body: {
        script: {
          lang: "painless",
          source: `ctx._source.myNestedObject.removeIf(object -> object.username == params.username);`,
          params: {
            username: "my_username"
          },
        },
      },
    };
    await client.update(documentUpdateInstructions);
```

This takes a document in the form of

```
document._source = {
  ...
  "myNestedObject": [
    {
      "username": "my_username",
      ...
    },
    {
      "username": "not_my_username",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

and deletes the object inside `myNestedObject` who's username matches the username provided (in this case `my_username`). The resulting document will be:

```
document._source = {
  ...
  "myNestedObject": [
    {
      "username": "not_my_username",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```