# elasticsearch - adding asciifolding filter to existing collection

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to add an asciifolding filter to existing elasticsearch index, but the query results are as expected. Though, when I apply the same procedure to the clean index it works as expected.

Does it mean that if I add a filter I have to somehow force the update over all documents to reindexed them or something?

Comment: Do you mean that they are NOT as you expected when you applied the filter to an existing index?

Comment: yes, the results are very wierd actually.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you add a filter you have to reindex the existing documents. [This](https://sematext.com/blog/2015/05/04/recipe-reindexing-elasticsearch-documents-with-logstash/) guide for reindexing Elasticsearch documents with Logstash will help you. Essentially, you will input the existing documents into Logstash, add your filter, and output them into a new index.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a filter/analyzer then the existing documents will not be affected (documents are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151566/why-are-documents-in-elasticsearch-immutable) in elasticsearch/lucene). This means that only the new documents will be saved with the new configs.

You can apply your new configs and then reindex any existing data. If you are using version 2.3 and later, then you can use the [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html) api. If not, then you'll have to use something like @pancake suggested or you could build a reindex mechanism of your own using the [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scroll.html), and [bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html) apis